# How to get last loaded ID when using infinite scrolling, ordered by column combined of two date columns?

Tags: php, mysql, infinite-scroll

I have messages table in which I store **message create date** and **message schedule date**(in case want to send later to the recipients)

Sample **MySQL** table data looks like below:

```
messages
------------------------------------------------------
id |message     |created_at   |scheduled_at |posted_by
------------------------------------------------------
1  |Lorem ipsum |2019-12-23   |2019-12-26   |1
2  |Lorem ipsum |2019-12-23   |NULL         |1
3  |Lorem ipsum |2019-12-24   |2019-12-25   |1
4  |Lorem ipsum |2019-12-24   |NULL         |1
5  |Lorem ipsum |2019-12-25   |NULL         |1
```

```
message_recipients
---------------------
message_id  |user_id
---------------------
1           |2
1           |3
1           |4
2           |2
2           |3
2           |2
3           |2
4           |2
5           |2
5           |5
```

```
users
------------------
id |name
------------------
1  |Lorem ipsum A
2  |Lorem ipsum B
3  |Lorem ipsum C
4  |Lorem ipsum D
5  |Lorem ipsum E
```

I am implementing infinite scroll. On page scroll reaching end of page, I am loading more messages in chunks from the messages table combining **created_at** and **scheduled_at**(less than current timestamp) columns and ordering with that column in DESC order to get latest records.

```
SELECT m.*, 
    (CASE
        WHEN m.scheduled_at IS NOT NULL THEN m.scheduled_at 
        ELSE m.created_at
    END) AS message_date
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN message_recipients mr ON m.id = mr.message_id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = mr.user_id
WHERE (u.id = 1) AND (m.scheduled_at IS NULL OR m.scheduled_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY message_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The problem is, I can not pass last fetched message ID to fetch next records greater than last fetched message ID because that can not be in chronological order due to sorting is with combined column of created_at and scheduled_at columns.

While `OFFSET` in query has performance issue and also can't make sure records will not repeat when new rows added to the database or will not skip rows when removed from the database.

Is there any other way to fix the issue with query or other way?

Otherwise, separating scheduled messages into another table and insert into main table using cron-job on scheduled date(to avoid get all data from both table to merge and sort by date)?

```
MariaDB: 10.1.38
PHP: 7.2.15
DoctrineExtensions: 2.4.26
jQuery: v3.3.1
AngularJS: 1.7.5
```